# I can't insert value in Google SpreadSheets (use nodejs & module googleapis)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

## I have this code

This is an example from Google Sheets API V4 https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs

But I need to insert a value in a spreadsheet, in the doc I see the append method for this case

I have the following function to append (Use **googleapis library**)

```
function addValues(auth) {
var sheets = google.sheets('v4');

val = Object.assign({
  majorDimension: "ROWS",
  values: [
    ["Hello","Google","Sheets"]
  ]
},sheets.spreadsheets.values)

//console.log("",val)

val.append({
  auth: auth,
  range: "A1",
  spreadsheetId: '1bhXbigMkNyTgKFVePZIwP5VZE1hN0XcvTRdeFdUSUdo',
  includeValuesInResponse: true,
  insertDataOption: "INSERT_ROWS",
  responseDateTimeRenderOption: "FORMATTED_STRING",
  responseValueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE",
  valueInputOption: "RAW"
}, function(err, response){
  if (err) {
    console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(response);
  })
}
```

...but it won't working

#### Console return the following messagge

> { spreadsheetId: '1bhXbigMkNyTgKFVePZIwP5VZE1hN0XcvTRdeFdUSUdo', 
>      tableRange: '\'Hoja 1\'!A1:C2', 
>      updates: 
>      { spreadsheetId: '1bhXbigMkNyTgKFVePZIwP5VZE1hN0XcvTRdeFdUSUdo',
>        updatedRange: '\'Hoja 1\'!A3',
>        updatedData: { range: '\'Hoja 1\'!A3', majorDimension: 'ROWS' } } }

It looks like the "values" array is not being sent

My complete code is in https://github.com/aaroncadillac/google-sheets-api/tree/test
The important file is quick.js, I hope you can help me 
 
Bye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved!!!

If you also went through this or do not know how to use **googleapis** you can review the official documentation of google api as this library is very subject to it, however is not documented in how to use google resources

The solution for this case is add the parameter "resource" to the principal object "parameters"

append function looks this way

```
sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
  auth: auth,
  range: "A1",
  spreadsheetId: '1bhXbigMkNyTgKFVePZIwP5VZE1hN0XcvTRdeFdUSUdo',
  includeValuesInResponse: true,
  insertDataOption: "INSERT_ROWS",
  responseDateTimeRenderOption: "FORMATTED_STRING",
  responseValueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE",
  valueInputOption: "RAW",
  resource: {
    values: [
      ["Hello", "Google", "Sheets"]
    ]
  }
}, function(err, response){
  if (err) {
    console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(response);
});
```